# angularjs search is not working while entering next text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hi I am using angularjs for search functionality. Search is working fine if I enter the keywords correctly.

i.e,

** ) Assume The array of value is ["Search Text Value" , "Search Text Sentense"].

** ) If I search "Search" in the text box, it is showing both of the value.

** ) If I search "Search Text Val", It is showing only "Search Text Value" result. Same for sentense also. These all are working fine.

** ) But instead of typing continiously, If I enter, "Search Value", or "Search Sentense", it is not showing anything. But I want to show the data, if I enter "Search Value", I need to show Search Text Value".

Please look at this fiddle,

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89p7q0mo/)

```js
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'store', function($scope, store) {
    $scope.search = '';
    $scope.products = [];
    $scope.products = store.getProducts();
    $scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(category) {
      $scope.search = category;
    };
  }]);

  // fake service, substitute with your server call ($http)
  app.factory('store', function() {
    var products = [{
      name: 'Apple Tasty fruit',
      category: 'Fruit',
      AddedBy: 'Anil Singh'
    }, {
      name: 'Apple Taste is sweet',
      category: 'Fruit',
      AddedBy: 'Anil Singh'
    }, {
      name: 'Cheese',
      category: 'Dairy',
      AddedBy: 'Anil Singh'
    }];

    return {
      getProducts: function() {
        return products;
      }
    };

  });
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */
   input[type=text] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>angularjs filter example Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
  <script>
    
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h2>Search Product: </h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="1" style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>AddedBy</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.category}}</td>
        <td>{{product.AddedBy}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

This is the example code. I have written the code like this,

```js
return cardDetails.filter(function (card) {
    return (!$scope.search || ($scope.search && $scope.search.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(function(str){
        return card.Tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) != -1;
    })));
 }).length > 0;
```

But this one is not working for me. How can I do this? Can anyone please tell me

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to make your search find products with names that match all of the search terms in any order.

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.loseKeywordFilter = function(keywords) {
  var keywords_regex = new RegExp(keywords.split(' ').map(function(i) {return '(?=.*'+i+')';}).join(''), 'i');
  return function(product) {
    return !!product.name.match(keywords_regex);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
[...]
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:loseKeywordFilter(search) | orderBy:'name'">
  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
  <td>{{product.category}}</td>
  <td>{{product.AddedBy}}</td>
</tr>
[...]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69tc20z8/

Comment: your answer is, if any keyword will match then it will show the result. See in the fiddle, if I search "Apple is", it should show only one result. But it is showing two of the results